# OPNET how to set datum to WGS84

Tags: opnet

I am testing simple terrain paths

I have some problems with locations in my maps with two different programs

I want to check if in my opnet the DATUM is set to WGS84

Any one knows where I can find it in the opnet gui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean OPNET of Riverbed, there is no ways to use the WGS84 coordinator.

Thanks,